# Where does amp; come from?

Tags: javascript, php

in javascript, I have:

```
var stop_symbols = $("#words_stop_symbols span").html().split('');
console.dir(stop_symbols);
```

html:

```
 <span>*/&amp;^\</span>
```

When php is simply:

```
<span>Array
(
    [0] => *
    [1] => /
    [2] => &amp;
    [3] => ^
    [4] => \
)
</span>
```

But in DB I only have character `&`

So where does this amp come from?

My final aim is to use this letters and get charCode for them using `str.charCodeAt(0);`

Comment: `&` is a special character in XML, when encoded it is `&amp;`. As you can see `&` is used to show some special characters via [entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: Do you call `htmlentities()` when printing the data read from the DB?

Comment: @Barmar nope, just json_decode

Comment: Could you show your actual PHP? Something is calling `htmlentities()`, either after reading from the DB or when storing into it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I discovered the problem html() -> text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering myself. Changing:

`html()` to `text()` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

"Ampersand" is the name for the character "&" in English. `&amp;` is the HTML code for "&".

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. Problem is, I don't want amp; but I need & to get the keyCode for it.

Comment: I want to apply: str.charCodeAt(0);

Comment: Ah. I'm a little confused at how you're getting this from PHP, but you might want to take a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Ohhhh. You say in the DB it's "&" but in PHP it's `&amp;` ... your DB table is probably actually holding `&amp;` but when you look at it with phpMyAdmin or a SQL browser you are seeing "&".

Comment: nope, checked it, mysql holds correct value. Now I'm starting to think it is html() that kills things.

Answer (score 1):

Use `html_entity_decode()`.

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Didn't help, actually in source I see <span>*/&^\</span> I'm not sure when it gets translated into amp :S

Comment: Then why does your question say: ` <span>*/&amp;^\</span>` ?

Comment: I copied it out from inspector. And in inspector all characters are translated to html entities, I realized that late and looked into source. Where it was &.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change

```
var stop_symbols = $("#words_stop_symbols span").html().split('');
```

in

```
var stop_symbols = $("#words_stop_symbols span").text().split('');
```

Comment: How is this different from [the other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19736727/1743880)?